# How would you code to count days using dateTimePicker in C#

Tags: c#

I need to put a code using C#. Need to could number of days once by using 2 `dateTimePicker` controls.
Anyone has any idea? I know how to do it in **vb.net** not sure how to do **in C#**.

vb.net code:

```
NumberOfDays = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, CDate(StartDateTimePicker.Text),
                                CDate(EndDateTimePicker.Text))
```

Comment: FYI you're being downvoted for a total lack of research. This is extremely simple and your question is quickly answered by a quick search.

Comment: Thanks for discuraging me using this site, instead of simply answering the question if it was extremely simple.

Comment: I would certainly discourage you from asking questions without doing any research or attempting the problem yourself, as exemplified in this post. This is essentially a "code it for me" question. It's extremely bad practice to do so, will get you in to trouble in the future, and is apparently agreed upon as bad etiquette by the 6 downvoters and the 5 users that flagged and closed your post. Please take the time to research and try it yourself next time, and if you run in to problems with a particular piece of code, I encourage you to use this site to work through the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
int NumberOfDays = (StartDateTimePicker.Value - EndDateTimePicker.Value).Days;
```

Or if you want to account for partial days:

```
double NumberOfDays;
NumberOfDays = (StartDateTimePicker.Value - EndDateTimePicker.Value).TotalDays;
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var numberOfDays = (EndDateTimePicker.Value - StartDateTimePicker.Value).TotalDays;
```